# Recursive SQL to eliminate duplicates?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a SQL, where I need to make assignments between ids, but only if there is exactling one "matching partner".

orig table:

| id_orig | id_new |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 98 | 200 |
| 100 | 200 |
| 100 | 300 |

First I need to find a way, to update all the pairs, where an id_new references exactly one id_orig:

`select id_orig, id_new from mytable QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_new) = 1`

this would result in the following resultset (1):

| id_orig | id_new |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 100 | 300 |

The problem is, that when I now look at the "rest of the set" (which in this case means every id, that wasn't part of the first resultset), there are new rows, which now exactly have one "matching partner".

```
WITH cte as (
select id_orig, id_new
from mytable
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_new) = 1
) 
select id_orig, id_new
from mytable
where id_orig not in (select id_orig from cte)
and id_new not in (select id_new from cte)
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_new) = 1
```

resultset 2:

| id_orig | id_new |
| --- | --- |
| 98 | 200 |

In reality, there could be many more steps needed to find all the "matching" partners, so my question is: is it possible to select the rows from resultset 1 and 2 with one query? Maybe recursively?

A brief summary of what I want to achieve:

1. Find all rows in the set, where id_new is unique
2. ( These ids are marked as "ready" in the source table, and will be ignored next time.)
3. Same as step 1: find all rows in the set, where id_new is unique (but ignore id's from the first resultset.. and so on).

Since I don't know how many times I would need to run these steps, until every row is found, I was wondering, if it was possible to select every row with one query.

Comment: What if the set is just a pair e.g.  `(20, 4), (20,5)`  or  `(4,20), (5,20)` ? Which row  should be excluded?

Comment: (4, 20) and (5,20) should not be in my resultset, because "id_new" would be ambiguous.  (20, 4), (20, 5) is kind of a "special case", which I haven't included in my example. In this case, I would prefer that both rows should be in my resultset.

Comment: You have `(98, 200),  (100, 200)` in the source table.  What if the source contains those 2 rows only?

Comment: The resultset should be empty.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, in your question basically what you are asking for is unique id_new with corresponding id_orig, the "rest of the set"  are rows that share id_new with at least one row and that are rows: (98,200) and (100,200), they still share new_id but the only thing that row (98,200) has and row (100,200) has not is unique id_orig. Is that the criteria for result set number 2, if not what is it?

Comment: And if that is the criteria for result set 2 how can the final result be empty if the table only contains this 2 rows: (98, 200),  (100, 200); because the query you described will return both rows.

Comment: I checked my queries with those two rows, you described (98, 200), (100, 200) and the resultset is empty, because of the qualify statement. Two entries with the same "id_orig" but different values in "id_new" are not allowed.

Comment: 1st) `(98, 200), (100, 200)`  these 2 rows have same `id_new` not `id_orig`. 2nd) The second query you posted returns both rows `(98, 200), (100, 200)` as a result if `mytable` has only those 2 rows.

Comment: Sorry, i mixed up the columnnames in my comment :( but nevertheless I don't get any rows as a result.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question to make it more clear what your intend is because you are contradicting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with the following approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id_orig, id_new
  FROM mytable
  QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id_new) = 1
),
final AS (
  SELECT id_orig, id_new
  FROM mytable
  LEFT JOIN cte 
    ON mytable.id_orig = cte.id_orig AND mytable.id_new = cte.id_new
  WHERE cte.id_orig IS NULL AND cte.id_new IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM final
```

This should return the non-matching fields between the first CTE and the rest of the set in `mytable`.